# Outlook Email Rules Geo-Location

Tags: outlook, office365, email-forwarding

I am doing some work for an organisation who has one main email account for client enquiries, but have three separate office locations.

The three locations are Dubai UK and USA, the client has asked if there is a way to receive an email in the main inbox and then auto forward it to the USA office if the sender was based in the US, so that there was no manual need to check the inbox or for lots of people to duplicate work or responses.

I don't think its possible and nothing form my research suggests it is possible?

I have tried to use the standard rules wizard in Outlook which has brought any useable results, and research the internet as well as spoken to other professionals.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is available out of the box, you'd need to write some code.

The best you can do is look at the MIME message headers (stored in the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` MAPI property and accessible through `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`) and check if the `Date` MIME header contains a UTC offset (like `-0700` below):

```
Date: Fri, 1 Sep 2023 21:27:19 -0700
```